# Create a vb.net windows service to download new uploaded files from server after every 1 hour

Tags: vb.net, windows, service

I need help to create a vb.net windows service to download new uploaded files from server after every 1 minute to local computer . This code download same file once the service started but timer is not working here.

I want to service detect the new file uploaded on server and download it and timer should periodically check new file after every  minute. Below is my code. Kindly help me.

**code:**

```
Imports System    
Imports System.IO    
Imports System.Threading    
Imports System.Net    
Imports System.Threading.Timer

Public Class Service1

    Dim MyThread As Threading.Thread
    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        Try
            Timer2.Enabled = True
            MyThread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf FTPDownloadFile)
            MyThread.Start()
            AddHandler Timer2.Tick, AddressOf Timer2_Tick
            Timer2.Interval = 60000 ' 1 minute time interval
            Timer2.Start()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub    

 Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()

        ' Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.

        Timer2.Enabled = False
        MyThread.Abort()

    End Sub

    Private Sub FTPDownloadFile()
        Dim ftpuri As String = ""
        Dim downloadpath As String = ""
        Dim ftpusername As String = ""
        Dim ftppassword As String = ""

        'Create a WebClient.
        Dim request As New WebClient()

        ' Confirm the Network credentials based on the user name and password passed in.
        request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("abc", "1234")

        'Read the file data into a Byte array
        Dim bytes() As Byte = request.DownloadData("http://iba-iet.netai.net/wordpress/home-2")



        Try
            '  Create a FileStream to read the file into
            Dim DownloadStream As FileStream = IO.File.Create("C:\file.html")
            '  Stream this data into the file
            DownloadStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
            '  Close the FileStream
            DownloadStream.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        MsgBox("Process Complete")

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        Try
            FTPDownloadFile()
            Timer2.Stop()
        Catch ex As Exception
        Finally
            Timer2.Start()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Timers
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Service1
Dim _oTimer As New System.Timers.Timer()
Dim _shutdownEvent As New ManualResetEvent(False)
Dim _processEvent As New ManualResetEvent(False)
Dim _thread As Thread
Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)

    'Setting Thread and Timmer to Pool for jobs
    _thread = New Thread(AddressOf Execute)
    _thread.IsBackground = False
    _thread.Start()
    AddHandler _oTimer.Elapsed, Function(sender, e) _processEvent.[Set]()
    _oTimer.AutoReset = False
    _oTimer.Interval = 10000
    _oTimer.Enabled = True

End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
    _shutdownEvent.[Set]()
    _thread.Join()
    _oTimer.[Stop]()
    _oTimer.Dispose()
End Sub

Private Sub Execute()
    Dim [handles] = New WaitHandle() {_shutdownEvent, _processEvent}
    Try
        While Not _shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0)
            Select Case WaitHandle.WaitAny([handles])
                Case 0 ' Shutdown Event
                    Exit Select
                Case 1
                    FTPDownloadFile()
                    _processEvent.Reset() ' reset for next time
                    _oTimer.Start() ' trigger timer again
                    Exit Select
            End Select
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub FTPDownloadFile()
    Dim FTPUri As String = "ftp://mywebsite.com/"
    Dim FTPUser As String = "abc"
    Dim FTPPwd As String = "123"
    Dim LocalPath As String = "C:\Myfolder\"

    Dim request As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(FTPUri), FtpWebRequest)
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory
    request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(FTPUser, FTPPwd)
    Dim response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
    Dim responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)
    Dim ListDirectory As New List(Of String)()
    Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()

    While Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(line)
        ListDirectory.Add(line)
        line = reader.ReadLine()
    End While

    reader.Close()
    response.Close()

    Using WebClient As New WebClient()
        WebClient.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(FTPUser, FTPPwd)
        For i As Integer = 0 To ListDirectory.Count - 1
            Dim LocalFilePath = LocalPath & ListDirectory(i).ToString()
            If ListDirectory(i).Contains(".") AndAlso Not File.Exists(LocalFilePath) Then
                Dim FTPPath As String = FTPUri & ListDirectory(i).ToString()
                WebClient.DownloadFile(FTPPath, LocalFilePath)
            End If
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks @Kashif. can you kindly figure out that how should i download the files periodically from server through vb.net windows service

Comment: the current code is set to call your **FTPDownloadFile()** function every 10 seconds `_oTimer.Interval = 10000`

Comment: I have added code for **FTPDownloadFile()** Sub to download multiple files that folder will have.

Comment: ahhh that was typo man. Code is self explanatory _Thread is Thread type.